# My HTML + JavaScript code works on online editors, but not offline

Tags: html, json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with Sheets, for converting google sheets into JSON files, and then with their API transform the JSON into javascript objects.

The problem is that the code works just fine in online editors just like Tryit from W3Schools or Codepen, but if I put it in an HTML file and open it with Chrome or Edge, it won't work. Does anyone know why? Will it work if I mount the site online?

```
<head>
  <!-- Add Sheetsu Web Client script to the head -->
  <script src="//script.sheetsu.com/"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="list"></div>

  <script>
    // API returns array of objects
    // Iterate over them and add each element as a list element
    function successFunc(data) {
      data.forEach(function(item, i) {
        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += "<li>" + item.Precio + " " + item.Tipo + "</li>";
      });
    }

    function errorFunc(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    Sheetsu.read("https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0su/110ccf6a6812", {}).then(successFunc, errorFunc);
  </script>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Also see the **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the script source and the `sheetsu.com` API source _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```html
<script src="//script.sheetsu.com/"></script>
```

When you start a resource/asset URL with "//" and without a protocol (http|https), it matches the protocol of where the page is loading. If you are opening a local html file directly, that protocol becomes `file://`, so the requested URL ends up being `file://script.sheetsu.com/`, which of course does not exist.

Change it to:

```html
<script src="https://script.sheetsu.com/"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Firefox and it worked. Check the image below:

[image: Image using local html file]